# Slack sign in with multiple Google accounts

Tags: slack

How can I sign in to two different slack.com sessions (foo.slack.com, bar.slack.com) using two different Google accounts? Once I'm signed in to one, when I attempt to sign in to another, it tries to use the same Google account. I need to use a different account for each.

Comment: Different browsers or browser profiles, I suspect.

Comment: Each team has its own domain, there's no reason it can't support multiple logins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a menu option in the dropdown on the top left (the label is the current team name). Open the menu and select "Sign in to another team...". I don't know if something has changed since my original question, but I'm now able to sign in to multiple teams simultaneously using different accounts. Previously, it didn't even prompt me to login; it just tried to re-use the credentials of the first team and failed.

Answer (score 0):

Once you sign in to one account, look for a plus sign on the bottom left, try adding the second organization and you should be able to switch between the two!